# `curl -O` stores an empty file though `wget` works well

Tags: command-line, wget, curl

I have tried to download a file from `https://logz.io/sample-data`.

```
curl -O https://logz.io/sample-data
```

However, it just returns an empty file named `sample-data`.

In contrast to `curl`, however, `wget` works well returning a file containing proper contents.

```
wget https://logz.io/sample-data
```

What have I missed with `curl`?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You've missed to follow redirections with `curl` as the URL endpoint is redirected (301) to another endpoint (`https://s3.amazonaws.com/logzio-elk/apache-daily-access.log`); sending a request with HEAD method (`-I`) to the specified URL:

```
% curl -LI https://logz.io/sample-data
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
...
...
Location: https://s3.amazonaws.com/logzio-elk/apache-daily-access.log
...

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
...
Server: AmazonS3
```

As `curl` does not follow HTTP redirections by default, you need to tell `curl` to do so using the `-L`/`--location` option:

```
curl -LO https://logz.io/sample-data
```

As `wget` follows redirections by default, you're getting to the eventual URL with `wget` *as-is*.